# Row sum with vector condition

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I've got a `data.frame` that looks like this:

```
              V1             V2             V3
1            143            143            143
2            141            141            143
3            195            195            141
4            121            121            121
5            142            142            142
```

I want to use `rowSums` to count the number of times a set of values appear in a row, e.g. the values `c(141, 143)`, so the answer would count, by row, the occurrence of the values in this vector:

```
3, 3, 1, 0, 0
```

Curious as to why this approach with `%in%` isn't working as expected:

```
rowSums(df[df %in% c(141, 143)], na.rm = T))
```

Thanks!

Comment: another one: `rowSums(!!as.matrix(df) %in% c(141, 143) * df)`

Answer (score 3):

Try this `apply()` approach:

```
#Code
apply(df,1,function(x) sum(x %in% c(141, 143)))
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 
3 3 1 0 0
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(143L, 141L, 195L, 121L, 142L), V2 = c(143L, 
141L, 195L, 121L, 142L), V3 = c(143L, 143L, 141L, 121L, 142L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the output if `df %in% c(141, 143)`... and consider that a data.frame is actually a list.

here is an alternative:

```
rowSums(df == 141 | df == 143)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably faster in an `sapply`.

```
rowSums(sapply(dat, `%in%`, c(141, 143)))
# [1] 3 3 1 0 0
```

Or even faster (even though it looks weird).

```
rowSums(t(do.call(rbind, lapply(dat, `%in%`, c(141, 143)))))
# [1] 3 3 1 0 0
```

*Benchmark:*

```
Unit: microseconds
                                                         expr     min       lq      mean  median       uq      max neval cld
                             rowSums(dat == 141 | dat == 143) 143.643 147.8535 155.86417 151.807 158.6965  227.584   100   b
                    rowSums(sapply(dat, `%in%`, c(141, 143)))  52.048  54.0900  58.10532  55.365  56.7685  181.658   100  a 
 rowSums(t(do.call(rbind, lapply(dat, `%in%`, c(141, 143)))))  37.505  39.8015  42.94497  41.077  42.2255  144.663   100  a 
           apply(dat, 1, function(x) sum(x %in% c(141, 143))) 149.256 153.5940 183.03378 155.890 160.2270 2560.057   100   b
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(V1 = c(143L, 141L, 195L, 121L, 142L), V2 = c(143L, 
141L, 195L, 121L, 142L), V3 = c(143L, 143L, 141L, 121L, 142L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `rowwise/c_across`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    rowwise %>% 
    mutate(Sum = sum(c_across(everything()) %in% c(141, 143)))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Rowwise: 
#     V1    V2    V3   Sum
#  <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1   143   143   143     3
#2   141   141   143     3
#3   195   195   141     1
#4   121   121   121     0
#5   142   142   142     0
```

#### data

```
df <-  structure(list(V1 = c(143L, 141L, 195L, 121L, 142L), V2 = c(143L, 
141L, 195L, 121L, 142L), V3 = c(143L, 143L, 141L, 121L, 142L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```